# Python filter and map json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm working on my home project and I tried to use filter and map functions to get the json values as I needed. I need to get the key and value that is related to the project.

No need to use `boto3`. Maybe comprehension list but prefers to stay within filter and map. Just wanted to see if anyone has success with multiple filter-map within one line.

I'm having issue with indices. As you can see `i[0]['Key']` gives me the first index, not the rest. Should be `0, 1, 2, 3 index etc.`

```
   {
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345678", 
            "InstanceId": "i-0000111",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Hey", 
                    "Key": "Project"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "adsf", 
                    "Key": "lol"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-0001111", 
            "InstanceId": "i-0000111",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "hehe", 
                    "Key": "oops"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "Hi", 
                    "Key": "Project"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)


h = filter(lambda i: i[0]['Key'] == "Project", filter(lambda x: x[0]['Key'], map(lambda y: y['Tags'], data['Vpcs'])))

print(h)
```

What I got the result is:

```
[[{u'Key': u'Project', u'Value': u'Hey'}, {u'Key': u'lol', u'Value': u'adsf'}]]
```

should be:

```
[[{u'Key': u'Project', u'Value':'Hey'}][{u'Key': u'Project', u'Value': u'Hi'}]]
```

Comment: That is not valid json syntax.

Comment: This is valid json.

Comment: You can check yourself, `[[{u'Key': u'Project', u'Value':'Hey'}][{u'Key': u'Project', u'Value': u'Hi'}]] ` is not valid json. Do you mean you can start second array without ending first one?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion.

Comment: That's your arbitrary choice, As per json rule this is not valid json string and also python cannot parse your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the list after `map(lambda y: y['Tags'], data['Vpcs']`. Try this:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)


h = list(filter(lambda i: i['Key'] == "Project", filter(lambda x: x['Key'], [e for elements in list(map(lambda y: y['Tags'], data['Vpcs'])) for e in elements])))

print(h)
```

result:

```
[{'Value': 'Hey', 'Key': 'Project'}, {'Value': 'Hi', 'Key': 'Project'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for solve the difficult part. Seems like I forgot to expand the list.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension.

**Ex.**

```
result = [[y for y in x['Tags'] if y['Key'] == 'Project']for x in data['Vpcs']]
print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[[{'Value': 'Hey', 'Key': 'Project'}], [{'Value': 'Hi', 'Key': 'Project'}]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this work as well and much shorter. I tried to upvote but my reputation is low since I’m new here.

Answer (score 1):

Use just slicing instead of map and nested filtering:

```py
h = [filter(lambda t: t.get('Key') == 'Project', vpc.get('Tags', tuple())) for vpc in data.get('Vpcs', tuple())]
```

or even better for reading

```
h = [[tag for tag in vpc.get('Tags', list()) if tag.get('Key') == 'Project'] for vpc in data.get('Vpcs', list())]
```

**Note:** everytime use `dictionary.get('key', default_value)` in production to avoid KeyError appearance in your code, if you doesn't wish so of course.

Comment: Thank you, this work as well and much shorter. I tried to upvote but my reputation is low since I’m new here.